# SELECT only TEXT COLUMNs

Tags: mysql

I want to select values of columns whose type is "text". Something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'mytable' AND COLUMN_TYPE='text') FROM `mytable`
```

Is it possible? I have searched a lot but found nothing, for which I am little bit pessimistic.

[Ofcourse the issue in above statement is 2nd SELECT returns multiple rows]

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: You've got to build your sql statement dynamically and then execute it, have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lot of statements here aside from the regular query not to mentioned you need to get the columns from `Information.Schema`. You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function along with [PREPARE and EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) statements.

And it will probably look like this:

```
SET @col = NULL;
SET @query = NULL;

SELECT (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) as ColumnNames
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE table_name = 'table_name' 
   AND data_type='text' )
INTO @col;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @col, ' FROM table_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See my <kbd>**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e7d3d/3)**</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'application_config' AND COLUMN_TYPE='varchar(150)';
```

**Note:** You have to mention exact type(EX:int(10), timestamp) otherwise use like ('%varchar%').

Comment: It seems OP wants to select columns with the exact datatype [TEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).